# Spark Streaming not parsing data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a very simple spark streaming job I created using the Jupyter which I am unable to get working. I was wondering if someone can point me what may be wrong here

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import scala.util.control.Exception.allCatch
import java.sql.Timestamp
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

def parseDouble(s: String): Double = try { s.toDouble } catch { case _ => 0.00 }
def isDoubleNumber(s: String): Boolean = (allCatch opt s.toDouble).isDefined

case class ProcessDataStream(Timestamp: String, TimezoneOffset: String, SystemGuid: String, TagName: String, NumericValue: String , StringValue: String)
```

**issue in the following code**, where I get to see the data in the `my_rdd_raw` but not in `my_rdd`

```
// Create the streaming context
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))
    val csvLines = ssc.textFileStream("wasb://container@storage.blob.core.windows.net/")

    csvLines.window(Seconds(60), Seconds(10)).foreachRDD(rdd=> {

        rdd.toDF().registerTempTable("my_rdd_raw")

        val processDataStream = rdd.map(s => s.split(",")).filter(
        s => s(0) != "Timestamp" && isDoubleNumber(s(4)) ).map(
        s => ProcessDataStream(s(0), 
                         s(1), 
                         s(2), 
                         s(3), 
                         s(4), 
                         s(5)))
        val streamDF = processDataStream.toDF()
        streamDF.registerTempTable("my_rdd")

    }
    )
    ssc.start()
```

the following code gives the result as expected

```
val data = sqlContext.sql("select * from my_rdd_raw")
data.collect().foreach(println)

[2016-04-19 20:26:01.0299,+05:30,ecc84966-9bc0-4bef-9cd2-ad79c25be278,test001,178.03499442294,,Good]
[2016-04-19 20:26:02.0303,+05:30,ecc84966-9bc0-4bef-9cd2-ad79c25be278,test001,160.205223861246,,Good]
```

but the query to `my_rdd` says table does not exist. Can some one please point out what is wrong in my code?

**EDIT 1**

I did make some progress on this and found that if I remove the following line

`.filter(s => s(0) != "Timestamp" && isDoubleNumber(s(4)) )`

this is working as expected. so does the stream processing work differently from the normal batch job?